# Connect Sheets with an api with live refreshing facility

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api, google-apps-script-editor

I need to **connect the api "https://coronavirus-19-api.herokuapp.com/countries"** **to google sheets** and want to **update it hourly or as soon as the api page refreshes**. Went through various tutorials but need help in parsing and executing it as a first timer.

Please try and implement by using the above mentioned api link. Thanks in advance!

Comment: The question need more details. Are you trying to use the Google Sheet API or Google Apps Script with the basic or advanced Google Sheets services? What kind of response gives the referred API?

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking is too broad. But I can show you how to get the data and parse it using python. The code goes as follows:

```py
    import json
    import requests
    from pprint import pprint

    data = requests.get("https://coronavirus-19-api.herokuapp.com/countries")
    data = json.loads(data.text)
    pprint(data[0])
    print("\n\n",data[0]["country"])
```

Here I am retrieving the data provided by the API and and parsing it with json. And then I printed the first index of the list followed by the name of the country in that index. 
The output look like this-

```
{'active': 809939,
 'cases': 1002529,
 'casesPerOneMillion': 0,
 'country': 'North America',
 'critical': 16346,
 'deaths': 57017,
 'deathsPerOneMillion': 0,
 'recovered': 135573,
 'testsPerOneMillion': 0,
 'todayCases': 6192,
 'todayDeaths': 822,
 'totalTests': 0}


 North America
```

[This](https://jsoneditoronline.org/) site may you to figure out how the data is stored in the json file.

And follow [this](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/python) to get started with the sheets api.